# How does numpy.linalg.inv calculate the inverse of a matrix?

Tags: algorithms, matrices, linear-algebra, python

What is the algorithm behind this routine and is there documentation available for it?

Comment: Did you check the numpy source code?

Answer (score 3):

The source code of this function is [here](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.26.0/numpy/linalg/linalg.py#L492-L562), which is a wrapper for a C++ function [here](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.26.0/numpy/linalg/umath_linalg.cpp#L1811), which is calling some BLAS/LAPACK library functions. Specifically, in order to compute the inverse of a matrix $A$, it calls the "[SGESV](https://www.netlib.org/lapack/explore-html-3.6.1/d0/db8/group__real_g_esolve_ga3b05fb3999b3d7351cb3101a1fd28e78.html#ga3b05fb3999b3d7351cb3101a1fd28e78)" routine to solve the equation $AX = I$ for the matrix $X$. (note that SGESV can solve arbitrary systems $AX = B$; $B$ does not have to be the identity matrix)

The SGESV routine first computes an [LU-decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LU_decomposition) of $A$: it finds a lower triangular matrix $L$ and upper triangular matrix $U$ such that $L U = A$. Solving a system with a triangular matrix is easy, as we can go row by row; we only need to solve an equation with one unknown variable for each row. So, we can solve $AX=B$ as follows: let $X':=UX$, then we have $LX' = A$ and $UX= X'$. These are both systems with a triangular matrix, and solving them gives $X$.